# How to add multiple HTTP headers dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

How do I add multiple HTTP headers **dynamically** in an AJAX call?
I have an array of objects containing which headers to add and their values like:

```
[
  {
    "headerName": "foo",
    "headerValue": "bar"
  },
  {
    "headerName": "some",
    "headerValue": "text"
  },
  {
    "headerName": "random",
    "headerValue": "values"
  }
]
```

I want to iterate over the array and add headers with its corresponding values in my AJAX call.

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'foo/bar',
    ...
    headers: {
       'key[0]':'value[0]',
       'key[1]':'value[1]',
            (to n times)
   },
   ...
});
```

I can use jQuery and Knockout in my project. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your question is you wish to iterate over an array of objects and add its key value pairs to another object. Isn't it?

Comment: So your question really boils down to, how do I turn this array of name/value objects into an object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can try something like:

```
headers = {}
$.each(array,function(i,val){
  headers.key[i] = array[i].headerValue;
})
```

Or maybe this should work:

```
headers = {}
$.each(array,function(i,val){
  headers.key[i] = val["headerValue"]; //since val is a JSON object here.
})
```

I haven't tried executing this code, you can refer to [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for help.